# Remove old versions of gems... gem cleanup is not doing it

Tags: ruby, gem

This is the list of gems of my system after issuing a `sudo gem cleanup` command:

```
activesupport (4.2.6)
addressable (2.5.0)
babosa (1.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.3.1, default: 1.2.0)
bundler (1.14.4)
capybara (2.7.0)
CFPropertyList (2.3.5)
claide (1.0.2)
cliver (0.3.2)
cocoapods (1.2.1)
cocoapods-core (1.2.1)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.1)
cocoapods-downloader (1.1.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0)
cocoapods-trunk (1.2.0)
cocoapods-try (1.1.0)
coderay (1.1.1)
colored (1.2)
colored2 (3.1.2)
commander (4.4.3)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.4)
credentials_manager (1.0.0)
declarative (0.0.9)
declarative-option (0.1.0)
deliver (2.0.1)
domain_name (0.5.20161129)
dotenv (2.2.0)
escape (0.0.4)
excon (0.55.0)
faraday (0.11.0)
faraday-cookie_jar (0.0.6)
faraday_middleware (0.11.0.1)
fastimage (2.0.1)
fastlane (2.15.1)
fastlane_core (1.0.0)
fourflusher (2.0.1)
fuzzy_match (2.1.0, 2.0.4)
gh_inspector (1.0.3)
google-api-client (0.10.0, 0.9.28)
googleauth (0.5.1)
highline (1.7.8)
http-cookie (1.0.3)
httpclient (2.8.3)
hurley (0.2)
i18n (0.8.0)
io-console (0.4.6, default: 0.4.2)
json (2.0.3, 1.8.3, default: 1.7.7)
json_pure (2.0.3)
jwt (1.5.6)
little-plugger (1.1.4)
logging (2.1.0)
memoist (0.15.0)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_magick (4.6.1, 4.5.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.1, 5.8.4, 5.5.1, default: 4.3.2)
molinillo (0.5.7)
multi_json (1.12.1)
multi_xml (0.6.0)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
nanaimo (0.2.3)
nap (1.1.0)
netrc (0.11.0, 0.7.8)
open4 (1.3.4)
os (0.9.6)
pdf-core (0.6.1)
phantomjs (2.1.1.0)
plist (3.2.0)
poltergeist (1.13.0)
power_assert (1.0.1)
prawn (2.1.0)
pry (0.10.4)
psych (2.2.2, default: 2.0.0)
public_suffix (2.0.5)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rake (12.0.0, 10.4.2, default: 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.2.2, default: 4.0.0)
representable (3.0.3, 2.3.0)
retriable (3.0.0, 2.1.0)
rouge (2.0.7, 1.10.1)
ruby-macho (1.1.0)
rubygems-update (2.6.10)
rubyzip (1.2.1, 1.1.7)
security (0.1.3)
sentry-raven (2.3.0)
signet (0.7.3)
slack-notifier (2.0.0, 1.5.1)
slop (4.4.1, 3.6.0)
spaceship (1.0.0)
terminal-notifier (1.7.1)
terminal-table (1.7.3)
test-unit (3.2.3, default: 2.0.0.0)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
ttfunk (1.4.0)
tty-screen (0.5.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uber (0.1.0, 0.0.15)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
unicode-display_width (1.1.3)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
word_wrap (1.0.0)
wwdcdownloader (20.17.0)
xcodeproj (1.5.0)
xcpretty (0.2.4)
xcpretty-travis-formatter (0.0.4)
xpath (2.0.0)
```

as you can see, several gems, like this one

```
minitest (5.10.1, 5.8.4, 5.5.1, default: 4.3.2)
```

have several versions installed and this `default` pointing to the oldest versions.

I want to delete all these versions keeping just the latest one and assigning the default to that latest one. `sudo gem cleanup` or even `sudo gem cleanup rjb` is not doing it.

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Could it be that some of the gems you have installed require older versions of others, preventing them from being just cleaned up?

Comment: is there a way to confirm that?